# Получить ответ от скрипта jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Надо удалить новость через js, просто взять и передать POST запрос на index.php. И после отправки оповестить alert.

Comment: весьма объемный скриптик получится. не?

Comment: @Jean-Claude - Вас это пугает? Вы профессионал или не профессионал?

Comment: @Igor неа)) нот профессионал.

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что _именно_ не получилось?

Comment: т.е. вы просто хотите, чтобы пользователи ru.SO написали скрипт _за вас_?

Comment: нет я хочу узнать как это сделать, гуглил большинство не понятные не рабочие примеры, вот и обратился на этот сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще всех этих примеров немерено в сети , но если так лень то вот тебе :
есть кнопка :

```
<button class="btn-bah-bah" data-del="3">Удалить несчастную новость</button>
```

Повесим на нее обработчик c кучей алертов:

```
$(".btn-bah-bah").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data("del");
  if (confirm("Удалить это?")) {
    $.post("ajax/index.php",{ "del":id} , function(data) {
      alert("Удалено с концами!" + data);
    });
  } else {
    alert("Славно , что ты не стал меня килять!")
  }
});
```

При нажатие на кнопку обработчик берет id удаляемой новости и отправляет его на index.php , предварительно задав вопрос )) , если ты согласен то запрос выполняется , если нет то новость тебе благодарна .

Comment: вывод сообщения "удалено с концами" произойдет если даже php-скрипт не удалит его)) Имхо надо `.ajax` c функициями `success` и `error`.

Comment: Предпологается что там железная логика))) , просто не охото развивать мысль , понятно что можно глянуть в data , что же там php вернул .

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки перебрал гугл, вот моё решение:

```js
function send(post)
{
   $.post('index.php', {dn:post}, function(data){
    getFile('/index.php?engine=news');
    });
}
```